# server side render skip sass compiling

Tags: webpack, node-sass

we are using node with react css-module, so component will looks like below:

```js
import react from 'react';
import styles from './style.sass';

export function test() {
    return <div classnames={styles}></div>;
}
```

and we have loader on webpack for serverside rendering, so we have two webpack files, one for `client` and another `server`, i am wondering if we can skip the server side sass compile as the loader below? so build time can be reduced.

```js
{
    test: /\.sass$/,
    loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=3&localIdentName=[folder]--[local]--[hash:base64:2]',
        'resolve-url',
        'postcss',
        'sass?sourceMap',
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `null-loader`, which simply returns an empty module instead of the imported one. This means that none of your `.sass` files would be included.

```js
{
    test: /\.sass$/,
    loader: 'null-loader'
}
```

Comment: Thx buddy I will give a try :)